# Logging-in always wrong credentials - Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I've customized the signup form according to my user table, after customizing it I tried signing up I filled up the password form using '123456' as a password. After finishing signing up it says the I input the wrong password?

Here's the method for the SignupForm model:

```
public function signup()
{
    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return null;
    }

    $user = new User();
    $user->username = $this->username;
    $user->email = $this->email;
    $user->setPassword($this->password);
    $user->generateAuthKey();

    $user->first_name = $this->first_name;
    $user->middle_name = $this->middle_name;
    $user->last_name = $this->last_name;
    $user->contact = $this->contact;
    $user->birth_date = $this->birth_date;
    $user->type = $this->type;
    $user->external_type = $this->external_type;
    $user->status = $this->status;
    $user->region_id = $this->region_id;
    $user->barangay_id = $this->barangay_id;
    $user->province_id = $this->province_id;
    $user->city_municipal_id = $this->city_municipal_id;

    return $user->save() ? $user : null;

}
```

User Model

```
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
}
```

I followed the right installation procedure of Yii2 advanced app, also I'm already done with the migration. Where did it go wrong?

Comment: Add validation rules of `User` model.

Comment: What do you mean validation rules of User?

Comment: Models in Yii2 have validation rules, which are used to validate user input data, they are located in function `rules()`.

Comment: how are you setting the password in `setPassword()` function ? add that function in your Question

Comment: @Yupik I already have the password on rules()             ['password', 'required'],
            ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6],

Comment: Edit your question and paste full `rules()` method.

Comment: The wrong password message appears when you try to create a new user or when logging-in?

Comment: Did you try a different password? `123456` might not be a "string" depending on how it's parsed.

Comment: @Idg I tried entering a different password like qwerty, it still doesn't work